# NGINX reading cached html file shows special character on web page

Tags: apache, caching, nginx, httpserver

### I'm using NGINX 1.4.4 with APACHE 2.2. NGINX creates cache file but when shame page is requested, cached file is read by NGINX and displays. Problem is the cached file contents are displayed as encoded characters on the web page. Following is my nginx.conf configuration.

```
#user       nobody;
worker_processes  5;  ## Default: 1
error_log  logs/error.log;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include     mime.types;    
    include     fastcgi.conf;
    include     koi-utf;
    #include    koi-win;
    index   cache.html cache.htm cache.php;


    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
            '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
            '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    #keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       localhost:88;
        server_name  localhost; 
        access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        charset utf-8;
        #charset windows-1251;
        source_charset koi8-r;

        # serve static files
        location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
            root    D:/docroot/ngnix/static/;
            expires 30d;
        }

        location / {

            include     proxy.conf;
            root   D:/docroot/ngnix/html/;
            #proxy_pass http://192.168.2.201:80;

            # if the request uri was a directory, store the index page name
            #if ($request_uri ~ /$) {
            #     set $store_extra ${request_uri};
            #}

            # set the location the proxy will store the data to. Add the index page
            # name if the uri was a directory (nginx can't normally store these)
            proxy_store D:/docroot/ngnix/html/${request_uri}cache.html;

            # go through the proxy if there is no cache
            if (!-f D:/docroot/ngnix/html/${request_uri}cache.html) {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.2.201:80;
            }

            # workaround. headers module doesn't take into account proxy response
            # headers. It overwrites the proxy Cache-Control header, causing
            # private/no-cache/no-store to be wiped, so only set if not using proxy
            if (-f D:/docroot/ngnix/html/${request_uri}cache.html) {
                expires 0;
            }

        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

### Following is koi-utf file

```
# This map is not a full koi8-r <> utf8 map: it does not contain
# box-drawing and some other characters.  Besides this map contains
# several koi8-u and Byelorussian letters which are not in koi8-r.
# If you need a full and standard map, use contrib/unicode2nginx/koi-utf
# map instead.

charset_map  koi8-r  utf-8 {

    80  E282AC ; # euro

    95  E280A2 ; # bullet

    9A  C2A0 ;   # &nbsp;

    9E  C2B7 ;   # &middot;

    A3  D191 ;   # small yo
    A4  D194 ;   # small Ukrainian ye

    A6  D196 ;   # small Ukrainian i
    A7  D197 ;   # small Ukrainian yi

    AD  D291 ;   # small Ukrainian soft g
    AE  D19E ;   # small Byelorussian short u

    B0  C2B0 ;   # &deg;

    B3  D081 ;   # capital YO
    B4  D084 ;   # capital Ukrainian YE

    B6  D086 ;   # capital Ukrainian I
    B7  D087 ;   # capital Ukrainian YI

    B9  E28496 ; # numero sign

    BD  D290 ;   # capital Ukrainian soft G
    BE  D18E ;   # capital Byelorussian short U

    BF  C2A9 ;   # (C)

    C0  D18E ;   # small yu
    C1  D0B0 ;   # small a
    C2  D0B1 ;   # small b
    C3  D186 ;   # small ts
    C4  D0B4 ;   # small d
    C5  D0B5 ;   # small ye
    C6  D184 ;   # small f
    C7  D0B3 ;   # small g
    C8  D185 ;   # small kh
    C9  D0B8 ;   # small i
    CA  D0B9 ;   # small j
    CB  D0BA ;   # small k
    CC  D0BB ;   # small l
    CD  D0BC ;   # small m
    CE  D0BD ;   # small n
    CF  D0BE ;   # small o

    D0  D0BF ;   # small p
    D1  D18F ;   # small ya
    D2  D180 ;   # small r
    D3  D181 ;   # small s
    D4  D182 ;   # small t
    D5  D183 ;   # small u
    D6  D0B6 ;   # small zh
    D7  D0B2 ;   # small v
    D8  D18C ;   # small soft sign
    D9  D18B ;   # small y
    DA  D0B7 ;   # small z
    DB  D188 ;   # small sh
    DC  D18D ;   # small e
    DD  D189 ;   # small shch
    DE  D187 ;   # small ch
    DF  D18A ;   # small hard sign

    E0  D0AE ;   # capital YU
    E1  D090 ;   # capital A
    E2  D091 ;   # capital B
    E3  D0A6 ;   # capital TS
    E4  D094 ;   # capital D
    E5  D095 ;   # capital YE
    E6  D0A4 ;   # capital F
    E7  D093 ;   # capital G
    E8  D0A5 ;   # capital KH
    E9  D098 ;   # capital I
    EA  D099 ;   # capital J
    EB  D09A ;   # capital K
    EC  D09B ;   # capital L
    ED  D09C ;   # capital M
    EE  D09D ;   # capital N
    EF  D09E ;   # capital O

    F0  D09F ;   # capital P
    F1  D0AF ;   # capital YA
    F2  D0A0 ;   # capital R
    F3  D0A1 ;   # capital S
    F4  D0A2 ;   # capital T
    F5  D0A3 ;   # capital U
    F6  D096 ;   # capital ZH
    F7  D092 ;   # capital V
    F8  D0AC ;   # capital soft sign
    F9  D0AB ;   # capital Y
    FA  D097 ;   # capital Z
    FB  D0A8 ;   # capital SH
    FC  D0AD ;   # capital E
    FD  D0A9 ;   # capital SHCH
    FE  D0A7 ;   # capital CH
    FF  D0AA ;   # capital hard sign
}
```

### With first request it works proper as the response is from apache web server. When I re-request it reads cached page which looks like the below.

```
?М}koI?Юg?Ъ?MВ6??HVЯ!J?(C?ЕІzmYcищsh4?dU?,?XEWEЁщfvьҐЩ|юbЖuЁ?8ЮX`В0?S?_"л
/ы?|TeЯ!?2уФt[щ&????????Y??кЭЧшЩДАЁ?ЁЪrrH?Qо%'/<9: ыB?ТUЕ?TzxЖ?ЭРЯыс'д,Д,?^Х
D?ОQЇT:<н?l7?ЗВJ?АpXV?~п)?=/ҐA\&???H+YЄ#;?ВЁL&Ё??{Ьм
??ъўЦҐ"щ€?ыeюW #9VиИяyр?Е{EгРЁ$`n#vЩ ??$/KJ{?х?F.??EыiXґP?lr?f?ын?W?т,?
F}жхFЛMTБ©;?МЩКi?Г??|??°1Yуx?ИU,?Ьй<дWnPукв? g· ?WU0^Тй ?mЙYё?Ъі?Z(ЁІІкяМас
зоґюИG?! <гК?Ї?у?ж?NЮхиЁЩ!?|?eжзоBe$~?y<Ъ+·?Н:Т2Tв8?4dА"BГQ?l# /$HnS
s]ч?uцьЮйзь?'Л сьmф?€AОBуj?X??Зўш?AхFю??Ь3 R|ЖЭ вЇ(??оІ0+РAШBЭ?-6Ю?sК??w$
?Є jЯ?Bpэкd?KДDп1P_wKБсw?·М?гgg'?ц_?8З??=ь?x|X8xv|ЖЭы?,а?цЦЁFV?убЖXD Йt?Ґ8Г?
,t?L?ТЕFЖt фGYцЯЧсцFЖоыhХv??E?R Н!?88хN?fрX©ЕG:нёЦ??©э ?·=yРЛ? Д.У:Ю
??сJрXы№?@шпО5ь2?ИHМT??Оw\єhю·O?К?Ё *іC?·сО?ЪZhnГ?m?ІЫC 8%s!?бt&ґОUХ4
М? й?ф?ЁG?-иw?ЇNНsҐЖ]'йГ>кґ?!???A +?U9P??_??ж?к?Nт?є?w?ZNf?€ЬзЫF?m Z?
Фю?v?ю6юi??]?& uъІ?M?Q?*9ЖоIы0к$Р =В?э!МюО??к?Йnп Н€е(TФ7?пFё?х?Л5?)?E
°pп ёFЙ??Aрeі"?+€DЩ6?^яЦЗг?лИ?б{?0ї?#л??+[@аQ?Q> ?д€ю?Xo6ю?Ф}7hтpў€
ыУ?)5ґ?є?фDзъ/d|h?І?щI?ю??'У?яr80OzG?;д5Х?>pЛ?'T)ХС
Є.Їц?л??}?$ц_2??CзбнёдO%0)???М[ч?Dщ#ЪT•K \/MPOтмq,kEю?ЧQb^ ?х1
жи}?є°ю? ?е?ЛFІ?Ґ?ё? КД?НлDuсH??©???N?2dх!ИяхB??"?#2є~?H1?З,GмMЛ*Уd
З;bBлщ=%5у?эiN??ЩX????]??с}?Tз? Kc Y?4bН?LUl??[ ·?6?Fс?+ПFC???@О=??G€<ж?К©AУb
`}?Ыy єOСjЭ[?OМQ^?і|??ёV&Ґ>мГН`?`Фж?]Ъ?ya ??ДґЙЯqn.$нмВГФбБэ\і87W\?3И?O?У?дY
qжg}?Б???8gр7M?X цИ^?E?sКU ? 2Р;W6VW?-?ZҐйИи"=]B??сHбZЭ:/ОЦ 
.КкQ?ъгєTтФСдLэl?4?{?y%????{|????6???КЩБ?Е6Y#?ў],???М=вїІзXd
```

### What is causing this problem? Please, correct me if my configuration is wrong.

Comment: Isn't it just a compressed version of the same page and somehow without proper headers?

Comment: Of course it is compressed data of the same page. but when it is read, it must decompressed and displayed. My question is why it is not decompressing.???

Comment: headers, when server answers the request it should indicate `Content-Encoding:gzip` start looking at the headers to understand if something overwrites it somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Modified nginx.conf and it works fine.***

```
#user       nobody;
worker_processes  5;  ## Default: 1
error_log  logs/error.log;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include     mime.types;    
    include     fastcgi.conf;
    #include     koi-utf;
    #include    koi-win;
    index   cache.html cache.htm cache.php;


    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
            '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
            '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    #keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    ######## additional Gun-zip configurations start #########
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied any;
    #gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml application/rdf+xml;

    # make sure gzip does not lose large gzipped js or css files
    # see http://blog.leetsoft.com/2007/07/25/nginx-gzip-ssl.html
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;

    # Disable gzip for certain browsers.
    gzip_disable “MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)”;
    ######## additional Gun-zip configurations end #########

    server {
        listen       88;
        server_name  localhost; 
        access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        # proxy module defaults
        proxy_store_access   user:rw  group:rw  all:r;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  Host       $host;

        #charset utf-8;
        #charset windows-1251;
        #source_charset koi8-r;

        # serve static files
        #location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
        #   root    D:/docroot/nginx/static/;
        #   expires 30d;
        #}

        # Main location
        location / {

            include     proxy.conf;
            root D:/docroot/ngnix/;
            index index.html index.htm;

            set $prefix  prefix_;

            # Use this if you don't cache a context (dont_cache_path) , send all requests through the proxy
            #location ~ ^/dont_cache_path {
            #   proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            #}

            # if the request uri was a directory, store the index page name
            if ($request_uri ~ /$) {
                set $store_extra index;
            }

            # set the location the proxy will store the data to. Add the index page
            # name if the uri was a directory (nginx can't normally store these)
            proxy_store D:/docroot/ngnix/${request_uri}${store_extra}.html;

            # go through the proxy if there is no cache
            if (!-f D:/docroot/ngnix/${request_uri}${store_extra}.html) {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.2.201:80;
            }

            # workaround. headers module doesn't take into account proxy response
            # headers. It overwrites the proxy Cache-Control header, causing
            # private/no-cache/no-store to be wiped, so only set if not using proxy
            #if (-f  D:/docroot/ngnix/${request_uri}${store_extra}.html) {
            #   expires 0;
            #}

            # handle static files directly. Set their expiry time to max, so they'll
            # always use the browser cache after first request
            location ~* (css|js|png|jpe?g|gif|ico|swf)$ {
                root D:/docroot/;
                expires max;
            }
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }

}
```